# Scroll Event in a particular DIV with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

What I am looking for is an event which fires when a scroll via keyboard takes place on a specific div. I have surfed and tried to implement several code snippets and plugin to achieve that but it did not help me. I have already implemented the same when I scroll within a particular div via mouse using mousewheel event and scrollTop function.

What I want is when a user scrolls in a particular div , the user should be navigated to another div / section.

The first screen with image is in a div on which i have implemented scrollTop on mousewheel. I want to implement the same functionality with scroll event via keyboard

You can see the live site http://www.eccentricengine.com/Demo/eccentric/ and view the source of what examples i have tried to implement.There is also possibility of conflicts in JS.

Answer (score 2):

see a small demo it may help you.click inside the div and press down or up key from key board.

```js
$("span").hide();
$(".box").scroll(function() {
    $("span").css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

```css
div.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here <br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here<br>
     text here
</div>
<span>Scrolling</span>
```

Comment: thanks..but i tried this long back but due to some conflict it does not seem to work..thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got you wrong, but you can just register an event-listener for the scroll event. So you don't need different events for keyboard, mouse, etc...

Here is a simple snippet:

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log('scroll event fires');
});
```

```css
.container {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #6Df;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Scroll me
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help..I solved my problem using flags of 0,1..
Setting flags depending on which div the cursor is.